# PIL ImageDraw.Draw attribute error 'Image' has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to draw the text 'we made it' onto an imported gif and display it on my notebook:

```
my_image = Image(url = 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1000/1*AmI9wRbXrfIWGESx6eEiTw.gif')

image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
image_editable.text((15,15), "We made it", (237, 230, 211), font=title_font)
my_image.show()
```

But I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py in Draw(im, mode)
    767     try:
--> 768         return im.getdraw(mode)
    769     except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'getdraw'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17400/3060345407.py in <module>
      1 my_image = Image(url = 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1000/1*AmI9wRbXrfIWGESx6eEiTw.gif')
      2
----> 3 image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
      4 image_editable.text((15,15), "We made it", (237, 230, 211), font=title_font)
      5 my_image.show()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py in Draw(im, mode)
    768         return im.getdraw(mode)
    769     except AttributeError:
--> 770         return ImageDraw(im, mode)
    771
    772

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py in __init__(self, im, mode)
     56            defaults to the mode of the image.
     57         """
---> 58         im.load()
     59         if im.readonly:
     60             im._copy()  # make it writeable

AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'load'
```

How can I get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting an error is because you aren't supposed to be passing the `url` to the `Image` class and then
pass this instantiated class to the `ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)`.

What you're supposed to do is use `Image.open()` then pass that resulting value to `ImageDraw.Draw()`.

According to the `ImageDraw` module [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html), you need to have the file available locally so
you need to actually grab that file and then do the following:

```
# assume you have the file downloaded as file.gif

my_image = Image.open('file.gif')

image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
image_editable.text((15,15), "We made it", (237, 230, 211), font=title_font)
my_image.show()
```